# Erro ao salvar no banco de dados Mysql

Tags: php

Não consegui descobrir porque as informações não salvam no banco de dados que criei no *PhpMyAdmin*.

[image: Erro ao salvar no BD]

Seguem os códigos abaixo:

`index.html`:

Nome
            Endereço
            Email

```
</body>
```

======================================================

`cadastroUsuario.php`:

```
<?php

    $nome = $_POST['Nome'];
    $endereco = $_POST['Endereço'];
    $email = $_POST['Email'];

    $server = 'localhost';
    $user = 'Saulllofelipe';
    $pass = 'Shika9573';
    $db = 'cvdd';

    $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $db);

    if ($conn->connect_error)
            echo "Erro<br>";
    else
            echo "Conectado com sucesso<br>";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO alunos(Nome, Endereço, Email) VALUES ('$nome', '$endereco', '$email')";


    if($conn->query($sql))
            echo "Seja bem vindo $nome<br>";
    else
            echo "Erro ao salvar<br>";

?>
```

Alguém pode me mostrar o erro e como resolver?

Comment: Os campos endereco é com ç? Coloque um ponto e vírgula no fim da query. Podem ser esses os problemas

Comment: Posta o html tbm.

Comment: Ao invés de colocar `echo "Erro ao salvar<br>"`, coloque `echo  $conn->error;`. Desta forma você saberá com precisão o motivo de não ter salvo.

Comment: Taí o arquivo HTML:

<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <body>
  <form method= "POST" action="criarUsuario.php">
   Nome<input type="text" name="Nome">
   Endereço<input type="text" name="Endereço">
   Email<input type="text" name="Email">
   <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </form>

 </body>
</html>

Comment: Pessoal aparece essa mensagem, mas não consigo identificar o erro.

Conectado com sucesso 
Você tem um erro na sua sintaxe SQL; verifique o manual que corresponde à sua versão do servidor MySQL para a sintaxe correta para usar perto de ' o, Email) VALUES (' Saulo ',' Carlos Alberto Sá, 50 ',' saulo @ gmail ')' na linha 1

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso, se não funcionar, pelo menos você saberá de onde vem o erro. Depois substitua `echo $conn->error;` por echo `"Erro ao salvar<br>"`.

```
<?php

    $nome = $_POST['Nome'];
    $endereco = $_POST['Endereço'];
    $email = $_POST['Email'];

    $server = 'localhost';
    $user = 'Saulllofelipe';
    $pass = 'Shika9573';
    $db = 'cvdd';

    $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $db);

    if (!$conn){
            echo "Erro<br>";


    }else{
            echo "Conectado com sucesso<br>";
    }   

    $sql = "INSERT INTO alunos(Nome, Endereço, Email) VALUES ('$nome', '$endereco', '$email')";


    if($conn->query($sql)){
            echo "Seja bem vindo $nome<br>";
    }else{
            echo $conn->error;
}
?>
```

Comment: Aparece essa mensagem de erro: 

Conectado com sucesso 
Você tem um erro na sua sintaxe SQL; verifique o manual que corresponde à sua versão do servidor MySQL para a sintaxe correta para usar perto de ' o, Email) VALUES (' Saulo ',' Carlos Alberto Sá, 50 ',' saulo @ gmail ')' na linha 1